# Is it syntactically correct/good practice to use use $# and $? in arithmetic test conditions?

Tags: bash, variable

I have seen a number of posts using

```bash
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then  
  return
fi

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  eval "set -- ${opts}"
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
```

for checking the value of "last exit status" and "number of positional parameters".

However, I have been using `$#` and `$?` as follows with no apparent problems:

```bash
if (( $? != 0 )); then
 ...
```

or

```bash
if (( $? == 0 )); then
  ...
```

So, is one of these approaches bad practice or a "stretch" of the syntax rules, with the other one being "the correct" way to use these variables? Or can one safely use both styles?

Comment: You are already using `$? ` in an arithmetic context when you test it with `-ne` so I'm not sure why you are asking about using it in another arithmetic context. Also, why are you even comparing it instead of testing with `if somecommand; then... ; fi`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `$?` (and `$#`) is a numeric value and you can use the arithmetic comparison constructs. Please note however that using `(( ... ))` as test construct is Bash-specific and scripts written that way may not be portable - that is different from the `$(( ... ))` arithmetic *expansion* which is a [POSIX standard feature](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04).

The reason why I would use the `[ $? -eq ... ]` (or, Bash-specific, the `[[ ... ]]`) test construct for checking `$?` is that in arithmetic context the `$` is unnecessary and therefore usually omitted from variable references, which however is impossible in case of `$?` (and `$#`).

The numerical range of `$?` is from 0 to 255<sup>(1)(2)</sup>. While you can in principle write a shell script that returns `exit -2`, calling `$?` after execution would (usually) show 254 (but note that not all shells allow this - some will say `sh: 1: exit: Illegal number: -2` instead).

---

<sup>(1)</sup> *As explained by @glenn jackman in a comment, the exit status is implemented as `unsigned char` variable and is therefore only guaranteed to accomodate the integer numbers 0 to 255.*

<sup>(2)</sup> *Additionally, as noted also by @Paul_Pedant in a comment, while the programmer of an executable may choose any value in the 0-255 range as exit code, 0 is usually used to indicate successful completion, and the shell may use values above 125 in a special way, as described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) e.g., so the exact value may be unreliable or at least difficult to interpret correctly in such cases.*

Comment: It is generally unwise to rely on exit statuses above around 120. Values 128 and above are generated by the Kernel when a process is terminated by a signal -- the return value is 128 + SigNum. `timeout` returns 124 it the child program timed out. Shells can return values just below 128 if they fail to execute an external command (e.g. if their fork or exec fails).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$?`, the status of the last process, is a numeric value, holding a value from 0 to 255.

However, using the string comparison operators `==` and `!=` on a numeric value is unwise. Use `-eq` and `-ne` instead. Read `man bash`.

Comment: While you are right, `==` and `!=` would be string operators only in the `[ ... ]` test constructs (and there you should indeed not use them for numerical comparison). In the arithmetic context `(( ... ))` (where the OP shows their usage) however they are actually the correct ones, i.e. `(( $? -eq 2 ))` would be a syntax error.